# How to make with twitter bootstrap tabs on hover instead of clicking?

Tags: tabs, hover, twitter-bootstrap

I finally got Bootstrap tabs to work. I was wondering if there's a way to change the behaviour so instead of clicking just hovering the cursor would show the hidden content?

Comment: Also, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Comment: The question is [answered here][1] using a few lines of css!


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In your `$(document).ready` or elsewhere ...

put something like this:

```
$('.nav-tabs > li > a').hover(function() {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

You wont have to modify the core bootstrap code.

Additionally you could do this:

```
$('.nav-tabs > li ').hover(function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('hoverblock'))
    return;
  else
    $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});

$('.nav-tabs > li').find('a').click(function() {
  $(this).parent()
    .siblings().addClass('hoverblock');
});
```

Which will prevent hover selection after the first time a user clicks a tab.

Answer (score 14):

It's better to bind a handler on the document object so it will work with dynamically generated tabs too:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[data-toggle="tab"]', function () {
  $(this).tab('show');
});
```

Also there is a small Bootstrap plugin which *automatically* activates tabs on hover: https://github.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs.

The complete HTML using this plugin is:

```css
body { padding: 2rem; }
.tab-content { margin-top: 1.5rem; }
```

```html
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Nav pills -->
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab-1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-3" data-toggle="tab">Tab 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab-4" data-toggle="tab">Tab 4</a></li>
</ul>

<!-- Tab panes -->
<div class="tab-content well">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab-1">Content 1</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-2">Content 2</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-3">Content 3</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab-4">Content 4</div>
</div>

<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/tonystar/bootstrap-hover-tabs/v3.1.1/bootstrap-hover-tabs.js"></script>
```

Comment: i guess you need to update your **Demo** link in your github page.

Comment: This is the best solution, but it no longer works for Bootstrap 5. What would be the necessary changes for BS5?

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript:

In your $(document).ready or elsewhere ...
put something like this:

```
$('.nav-tabs[data-toggle="tab-hover"] > li > a').hover( function(){
    $(this).tab('show');
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" data-toggle="tab-hover">
    ....
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modify `bootstrap.js` (or `boostrap-tab.js` if you aren't using the full `bootstrap.js` file)

Where you see:

```
 /* TAB DATA-API
  * ============ */

  $(function () {
    $('body').on('click.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-toggle="pill"]', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      $(this).tab('show')
    })
  })
```

change the `'click.tab.data-api'` to `'hover.tab.data-api'`

Note: I tested this with Bootstrap v2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Right from my production code. Orthogonal, unobtrusive, can "unclick" any user interface. Selector can be modified to match many kinds of clickables.

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.js-mouseover-to-click',function (event) {
    $(event.target).trigger('click');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope it is nice solution

```
(function ($) {
  $(function () {
    $(document).off('click.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-hover="tab"]');
    $(document).on('mouseenter.bs.tab.data-api', '[data-toggle="tab"], [data-hover="tab"]', function () {
      $(this).tab('show');
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var triggerTabList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link'))
triggerTabList.forEach(function (triggerEl) {
  var tabTrigger = new bootstrap.Tab(triggerEl);
  triggerEl.addEventListener('mouseenter', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    tabTrigger.show();
  });
});
```