# How to add options tabbed menu to mega drop-down menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using a code snippet from https://bootsnipp.com/snipps/vacation-rentals

This snippet provides the user with a chice of 3 options with tabbed menus.

Please check the **[website](https://bootsnipp.com/snipps/vacation-rentals)** and you will see how this tabbed menu works.

[image]

This is the code of this snippet

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span12">
                <div class="tabbable tabs-left">

                    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" style="padding-top:15px;margin-left:-20px;">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#A" data-toggle="tab">Apartman A2(1+1)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#B" data-toggle="tab">Apartman A4(2+2)</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#C" data-toggle="tab">Apartman A6(4+2)</a></li>

                    </ul>

                    <div class="tab-content">
                        <div class="tab-pane active" id="A">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="B">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                        </div>
                        <div class="tab-pane" id="C">
                            <img src="http://placehold.it/80x80">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div> <!-- /tabbable -->

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<hr>
```

However, I am trying to add this to my website and it gets effected from the upper li,ul behaviours and it doesn't work.

It becomes like this.

[image]

This is my website http://www.carantina.com

Please check **'PRODUCTS'** page and you will see what I mean.

If I can override preceding ul,li tag's style behavior and set them to default bootstrap styles, it may work. But I couldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because you have `tabbable` element inside `navbar`, and some of css styles referring to tabs are corrupted by navbar styles.

Try adding this style:

```
.navbar .tabs-left>.nav-tabs>li {
    float: none;
}
```

And search for other styles that gets corrupted. Although this could not be all that is not working well.

Comment: Now it is better but still there are some problems as you said. I have to modify couple of code I suppose. I am perplexed a little bit.

Comment: My advice: open bootstrap.css file(not minified), search for lines where `.tabbable` element is defined, copy all of it(or only some parts if you know what you exactly need) and prepend each rule with `.navbar`

Comment: I don't want to edit the core a lot. But if nothing works I will try to do that.

Comment: So you can just add some custom class to your tabs and use it instead of `.navbar` class in overrided rules. That way it will only apply to elements with that custom class.

Comment: I think I will do as you said. I have a small question. Normally I have to click tab in order to change the tab. How can I modify my code and when I hover on the tab it can behave like it is clicked?

Comment: This should be exactly what you want: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815247/how-to-make-with-twitter-bootstrap-tabs-on-hover-instead-of-clicking