# How can I make a Twitter Bootstrap 'Split button dropdown' dropdown on hover rather than click?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a [Twitter Bootstrap split button dropdown](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonDropdowns). How can I get it to dropdown when it is hovered over, rather than when the arrow is clicked?

This is similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click), but for a different Twitter Bootstrap element.

Answer (score 4):

The solution to this is nearly the same as the question in your link.  You need to add some CSS to the :hover pseudo selector that will display the dropdown. The hovered element must encompass both the button, and the dropdown list. In the example below, I added the `btn-hover` class to the button group to act as my hover selector.

```
        <div class="btn-group btn-hover">
          <button class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
            Action
            <span class="caret"></span>
          </button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Test</a></li><!-- dropdown menu links -->
            <li><a href="#">Test 2</a></li><!-- dropdown menu links -->
          </ul>
        </div>
```

CSS:

```
div.btn-group:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
    display: block;    
}

div.btn-group ul.dropdown-menu{
    margin-top: 0px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for larger device hover effect and smaller device click effect:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.dropdown').append("<style type='text/css'>@media screen and (min-width: 768px) { .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {display: block;} }</style>"); 

});
```