# Twitter Bootstrap sideways caret

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Twitter Bootstrap and some custom css (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10143018/351614)) to have dropdown menus open up on mouseover.

I am using the "caret" on a  on the root menu items to show the user there is more options available, I would like to use a sideways version of this for the sub menus, in that example they use a -> image however I don't think it really fits in with the rest of the UI.

I've also tried the play icon twitter has but it doesn't quite match either.

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Just switch up the borders ([see fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6zuY/)):

**HTML**

```
<b class="caret-right"></b>
```

**CSS**

```css
.caret-right {
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
    border-left: 4px solid;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0.3;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I do it by adding a class that simply modifies the border styles to point the caret to the right. That way you can toggle a caret right/down by adding/removing the modifying class.

HTML:

```
<span class='caret caret-right'></span>
```

CSS:

```
.caret-right {
    border-left: 4px solid;
    border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
    border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the bootstrap (3.0) Glyphicons

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up"></span> <!-- UP -->
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span> <!-- DOWN-->
```

Answer (score 5):

As user2661940 said you can use glyphicons for Bootstrap 3 or you can also make your own class for every side.
For example

```
.caret-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 4px solid;
  border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;
  border-top: 4px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I use these styles to do that (it works without bootstrap as well)

**HTML:**

```
<span class="caret up"></span>
<span class="caret right"></span>
<span class="caret down"></span>
<span class="caret left"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.caret {
    border: 5px solid transparent;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.caret.up {
    border-bottom: 5px solid;
}
.caret.right {
    border-left: 5px solid;
}
.caret.down {
    border-top: 5px solid;
}
.caret.left {
    border-right: 5px solid;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option for anyone using font awesome:

```
<i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Answer (score 4):

I added a rotation class to the span

HTML:

```
<span class="rotate270 caret"></span>
```

CSS:

```
.rotate270 {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

You can obviously create other angle classes as desired.

Answer (score 3):

you can use simple code:

**HTML**

```
<span class="caret"></span>
```

**CSS:**

```
.caret{
border-color:#ffffff transparent transparent transparent;
border-width:4px;
border-style:solid;
content: ""
display:inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the css to rotate the caret on mouse hover

```
.navbar-nav>li>.dropdown-menu{
    display:block;
    visibility:hidden;

}
.navbar-nav>li:hover>.dropdown-menu{
    visibility:visible;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li:hover>a .caret{
    transform:rotate(-90deg);
    transition:all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```