# Bootsrap Carets: Making sub carets and float them to the right?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, caret

How can I `float` or make all my caret to the **right**?

I follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10747267/twitter-bootstrap-sideways-caret) to make sub carets in my menu.

But it displays the carets to be `inline-block` and that my sub carets don't look align.

[image]

I would want the sub carets to be align like this,

[image]

Is it possible?

css,

```
.caret-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-left-color:#999999;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

html,

```
<li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Category <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li class="el-dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" style="border:1px solid red;">News - a very long title <b class="caret-right"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#/3">Add</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/4">Manage</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="el-dropdown-submenu"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Blog <b class="caret-right"></b></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Add</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Manage</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
```

**EDIT:**

If I float the `display` to `right`,

[image]

Comment: Please paste your HTML and CSS

Comment: Sorry I forgot! please see my edit above thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you should change your markup. `<caret>` div should before the text. Then you can give float right;

**[Working Demo](http://www.bootply.com/115423)**

```
<b class="caret-right"></b>  
News - a very long title
```

**CSS**

```
.caret-right {
float:right;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-left-color:#999999;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-right:-8px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add `float: right`

```
.caret-right {
  float: right; /*Added */
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-left-color:#999999;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```

Comment: Can you do a jsFiddle?

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/9Hf6c/ but I dunno how to make Bootsrap to work on jsfiddle. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Old question but you can do this simply by adding class="pull-right".

```
<li><a href="#">2011 <span class="caret-right pull-right"></span></a></li>
```

CSS

```
.caret-right {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  margin-left: 2px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-left: 5px solid;
  border-left-color:#1c2b36;
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
}
```