# twitter bootstrap jquery dropdown menu how to delay toggle

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

out` in
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns
In previouse question I asked about drop down onmouseover i as anwser i got

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{
   display: block;    
}
```

But problem is when U are not on cloud and menu spot (this is this place between black and white one) menu is toggle-out

[image]

How to change the script to ract on mouseove and mouseout and not on click ??

Comment: take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Answer (score 0):

```
.navbar .dropdown-menu {
   margin-top: 0px;
 }
```

Comment: I dont't want to change nothing in `css` just `js`

Comment: @skowron-line can you provide an working example in jsFiddle?