# How to make Bootstrap's dropdown on hover?

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap

How can I make twitter bootstrap's menu dropdown be on hover instead of a click?

Comment: You can simple do this using pure css, http://stackoverflow.com/a/22365311/861607

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click) has been upvoted a lot, with the newer versions of Bootstrap, no need to hack at it.

http://cameronspear.com/blog/twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-on-hover-plugin/ is a replacement for the existing dropdown.js, and lets you enable on hover. No CSS modifications required.

Answer (score 15):

1.Hide *dropdown-menu* on **mouseover**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    }, function() {
        $(this).removeClass('open');
    });
});
```

2.Hide *dropdown-menu* on **click**.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass('open');
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/7yMsQ/1/

Comment: Also add `$('.nav li.dropdown').removeClass('open');` as the first line in the 2nd (closing) function, so that if you have multiple dropdowns it hides the others that may be open.

Answer (score 6):

heres a function I'm using to get the navbar dropdowns to slide down on hover instead of just popping in

```
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp()
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply do this by using only css. In case of button dropdown.

```
   <div class="btn-group btn-hover-group">
      <a href="#" id="selected" class="btn btn-default editor-submit">Action 1</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu pull-right">
        <li><a href="#" id="all" class="editor-submit">Action 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="matching" class="editor-submit">Action 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

Removed `data-toggle="dropdown"` from `<a href="#" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"></a>`

```
.btn-hover-group > a:hover ~ ul{
 display:block;
}
.btn-hover-group > .dropdown-menu:hover{
 display:block;
}
```

I hope this will suffice your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a bootstrap 4 like this..

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

then define the class property value following..it should work

```
.dropbtn {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}
```