# Bootstrap dropdown menu show on hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can i change the dropdown menu to open on hover?

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="Eventos">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <p>
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning dropdown-toggle btn-xs" data-toggle="dropdown"></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
          <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Found this:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu{
display: block;   
}
```

But isn't working in this case (tabs?)

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover)

Answer (score 1):

Use an adjacent CSS selector..

```
.dropdown-toggle:hover + ul.dropdown-menu {
   display: block;   
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/85298

Comment: Thanks @Skelly but the menu fades out before the mouse go into it.

Comment: Yeah I missed that.. Is the only way with JS/jQuery?