# Activating bootstrap dropdown menu on hover

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some problem with activating bootstrap dropdown menu on hover - it only works on click. Here is the Bootply version: [Bootply version](http://www.bootply.com/T7O4Mwy29n)

Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover)

Comment: It is a different type of menu so it is not a duplicate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Existing Code Solution

To use your existing code, add the following line to your hover listener:

```
$($(this).data('target')).collapse('show');
```

Working fork of your bootply: http://www.bootply.com/FRv5lVuiJk

### Refactored Code Solution

That being said, there is a more effecient way of doing this using tabs. See http://www.bootply.com/TjqIiOM7Hi for a working example, and the code is below.

HTML

```
<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" id="topmenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown active">
    <a href="#one" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#two" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>
  </li>
  <li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#three" data-toggle="tab">Three</a>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default right tab-content" role="navigation" id="submenu">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav tab-pane active" id="one">
  <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">One sub 4</a></li>
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav tab-pane" id="two">
  <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">Two sub 3</a></li>
</ul>
 <ul class="nav navbar-nav tab-pane" id="three">
  <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="">Three sub 2</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$('[data-toggle=tab]').hover(function (e) {
  $(this).click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this. No JavaScript needed

### HTML:

```
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="">
            <a class="">Dropdown</a>
        </button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
        <a class="dropdown-item">Item 1</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Item 2</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item">Item 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

you can obviously change the style to your preference but the code relating to the display is important.

### CSS:

```
/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 1;
}
/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}
/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd;
}
/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}
/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color:#6c757d;
}
```

Just slot in the menu in the position you want along with your bootstrap classes.