# angular-bootstrap dropdown on mouseenter and keep dropdown-menu from hiding before being clicked.

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, angular-bootstrap

First, I'm aware of this posts:
[Activating bootstrap dropdown menu on hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24649366/activating-bootstrap-dropdown-menu-on-hover)
[Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover)
[How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)
And others, but still not found the correct solution yet, here's what I did so far.
first I used the is-open attribute from the angular-bootstrap dropdown directive like this:

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
  <a
    href
    class="dropdown-toggle"
    ng-mouseenter="status.isopen = true"
    ng-mouseleave="status.isopen = false"
  >
    hover me for a dropdown with angular-bootstrap
  </a>
  <ul
    class="dropdown-menu"
  >
    <li ng-repeat="choice in items">
      <a href>{{choice}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

that seemed to work but 2 bugs appeared:

- **the first** is when dropdown-toggle element is clicked the dropdown menu is gone clicking again wont bring it back you have to mouseleave then mouse enter the dropdown-tooggle to get the dropdown-menu back.
- **the second** is a css/html problem.

Usually the regular css solution for a dropdown is like this:

```
<a class="css-dropdown">
  hover here with css.
  <div class="css-dropdown-menu">
    <p>item 1</p>
    <p>item 2</p>
    <p>item 3</p>
  </div>
</a>
```

**Notice** the dropdown-menu now is inside the dropdown-toggle element which mean when moving with the mouse from the dropdown-toggle to the dropdown-menu it's moving from parent to child, so basically we still hovering over the dropdown-toggle since we are in it's child, which mean the dropdown-menu will still be visible, on other hand, the bootstrap dropdown works with the click event so having the dropdown-menu as a child of the dropdown-toggle is not needed, but now when someone wants to change the behavior to mouseenter/hover once the mouse leaves the dropdown-toggle the dropdown-menu disappear so we no longer have access to the dropdown-menu elements this is visible in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UPvQ31fOo6CXD0kPbIKs?p=preview)

To fix the first bug, I just removed the dropdown directive then replaced the is-open with ng-class directive like this.
Change this:

```
<span class="dropdown" dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
```

to this:

```
<span class="dropdown" ng-class="{'open': status.isopen}">
```

The rest stays the same [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fLnEgIwHXrl6B2oik9BS) that fixed the first bug.
The second bug is tricky, since the dropdown-menu is no longer a child of the dropdown-toggle the hover effect wont last while moving from the toggle to the menu, so I did this.
Changed this:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
```

to this:

```
<ul
  class="dropdown-menu"
  ng-mouseenter="status.isopen = true"
  ng-mouseleave="status.isopen = false"
>
```

That did it but another bug appeared when clicking the dropdown-menu item it stays open, so I kept hacking by doing this.
changed this:

```
<li ng-repeat="choice in items">
```

to this:

```
<li ng-repeat="choice in items" ng-click="status.isopen = false">
```

That give me the required behavior [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/I8QkIlHKMMGR1QsDOWt2?p=preview).
That said, this is not a good solution since a lot of directives are involved here for a simple visual effect, the last plunker I provided contains a css solution with no Bootstrap or AngularJS involved, though it is the required behavior it is not the required html structure or visual result, what I need is to have a space between the dropdown-toggle and the dropdown-menu not a padding of the toggle element just an empty space, which make the css solution not valid in this situation.
So, my question is there a better way of doing this without adding a new plugin/library more clean and easily reusable solution for the hover drop down menu?

Comment: Have you fixed this issue ? Or is it still open which i believe should be closed as of now :)

Comment: no, I didn't work on this yet I had too much other stuff, it still using the same hack I mentioned here :(, if you have a better solution cleaner with less directives I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Let me check, i will get back to you

Comment: Hi have u got any good solution apart from the above mentioned ones

Comment: @AvinashSolanki, no.

Answer (score 5):

**First**, have the toggling on the *top-most parent element* (in this case, the `<span>`)

```
<span class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="status.isopen" ng-mouseenter="status.isopen = true" ng-mouseleave="status.isopen = false">
  <a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" dropdown-toggle>
    Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</span>
```

This will allow the behavior you wanted - while still allowing clicking to show/hide the menu ;-)

However there's an annoyance: if you move the mouse cursor slower and pass the small gap between the toggle and menu, it will hide the menu.

So **secondly**, add a small CSS to remove the gap

```
.dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

See the action in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/CIvJTBr63AzTqTx78Zss?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

I know you want a solution *`without adding a new plugin/library`*, but you (or others seeking for this behavior) might want to try using [No Close from Dropdown Enhancements lib](http://behigh.github.io/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/#inputs-noclose) to keep the dropdown open even after clicking in one of its options:

> Do not close the menu on click on radio add class `.noclose`.

```
<div class="btn-group">
  <button data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">
      Checked option <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu noclose">
      <li>
          <input type="radio" id="gr1_1" name="gr1" value="1">
          <label for="gr1_1">Option 1</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="radio" id="gr1_2" name="gr1" value="2">
          <label for="gr1_2">Option 2</label>
      </li>
      <li>
          <input type="radio" id="gr1_3" name="gr1" value="3">
          <label for="gr1_3">Option 3</label>
      </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Also add a CSS solution for the hovering problem:

```
.btn-group:hover .dropdown-menu.noclose {
    display: block;
}
.dropdown-menu.noclose {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

And, of course, don't forget to import the libs:

- [`<script src="./js/dropdowns-enhancement.min.js"></script>`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/behigh/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/master/dist/js/dropdowns-enhancement.js)
- [`<link href="./css/dropdowns-enhancement.css" rel="stylesheet"\>`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/behigh/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/master/dist/css/dropdowns-enhancement.css)

---

In your case I suggest you to study the [Dropdown Enhancements's source code](https://github.com/behigh/bootstrap_dropdowns_enhancement/blob/master/dist/js/dropdowns-enhancement.js) to see how it works and maybe find a more suitable solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to your css:

```
.btn-group:hover>.dropdown-menu { display: block; margin-top: 0; }
```

You'll have to remove your is-open, ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave directives.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution I came up with, while working on the same issue.

I used a simple custom directive that:

- binds the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events to the dropdown in order correctly to show/hide the menu.
- dynamically adds a custom CSS class to the dropdown menu in order to prevent the menu from disappearing when moving the cursor from the button to the menu. **Note that this solution has the advantage of not removing the visual gap between the button and menu**.
- prevents the menu from disappearing when the button is clicked.

The CSS rule uses a `before` pseudo-element to fill the gap between the button and the menu. I added the `border` property which can be uncommented to easily get a visual feedback.

```css
.dropdown-hover-menu::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

The HTML structure of the snippet is based on the available examples in the [dropdown section of the angular-ui bootstrap documentation](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/dropdown)

```js
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap'])
  .directive('dropdownHover', function() {
    return {
      require: 'uibDropdown',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, dropdownCtrl) {

        var menu = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.dropdown-menu')),
          button = angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.dropdown-toggle'));

        menu.addClass('dropdown-hover-menu');

        element.bind('mouseenter', onMouseenter);
        element.bind('mouseleave', onMouseleave);
        button.bind('click', onClick);

        function openDropdown(open) {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            dropdownCtrl.toggle(open);
          });
        }

        function onMouseenter(event) {
          if (!element.hasClass('disabled') && !attrs.disabled) {
            openDropdown(true);
          }
        };

        function onMouseleave(event) {
          openDropdown(false);
        };

        function onClick(event) {
          event.stopPropagation();
        }

        scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
          element.unbind('mouseenter', onMouseenter);
          element.unbind('mouseleave', onMouseleave);
          button.unbind('click', onClick);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
.dropdown-hover-menu::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: -3px;
  height: 3px;
  /*border: 1px solid black;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.3.3/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div ng-app="app">
  <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown dropdown-hover>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle">
      Button dropdown <span class="caret"></span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu">
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Action</a>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Another action</a>
      </li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Something else here</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li role="menuitem"><a href="#">Separated link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```