# Bootstrap on hover button dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want dropdown-menu to appear on mouse hover. Here is jsbin of my code: [link](http://jsbin.com/wajagoqene/1/edit?output)

Tried jquery:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn();
    }
);
$('.dropdown-menu').hover(
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true);
    },
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut();
    }
);
```

But it is not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover) this is fixed using CSS instead of JavaScript. If you change the solution of the accepted answer into

```
.navbar .btn-group:hover > .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

it should work with your example code.

Comment: But dropdown menu is disappearing

Comment: Good point :D! I've changed the CSS to look at the `.btn-group` instead of the `button` as the `.btn-group` contains both the button and the dropdown-menu. the `>` is needed as there is another `.btn-group` around all buttons, so without it hovering any button would open all menu's :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use inner Bootstrap API:

```
$(document)
   .on('hover', '.dropdown-toggle', Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
    }, function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp();
    });
    $('.navbar .dropdown > a').click(function () {
        location.href = this.href;
    });
});
```