# Drop down menu on hover the navigation bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I want to create a drop down menu like this website http://www.jamieoliver.com/ .
To see the drop down menu, just hover the navigation bar on this http://www.jamieoliver.com/ website

Comment: Please attempt this for yourself before asking. Show some code that you've tried and then some can then help you

Answer (score 1):

You should see this questions:

[Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover)

[How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click),

Anyway, you should have provided some code or some tries you have done before asking as @Chris Beckett said.

Comment: **This is really a comment, not an answer.**  I appreciate that you may not yet have sufficient reputation to leave comments but please do not use the answer system as a replacement. Gaining reputation is fairly easy and only requires a little effort on your part. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much for understanding my situation @Paulie_D!

Answer (score 1):

Here a quick example for you to have a look at. In the future please try and attempt to do this yourself before asking a question on here. That way least you've given it a go before someone has handed you it on a spoon.

**HTML:**

```
  <body class="news">
  <header>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li class="tutorials"><a href="#">Tutorials</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Tutorial3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="about"><a class="active" href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="news"><a href="#">Newsletter</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#">News1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="contact"><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #ccc;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  background-color: #444;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav li {
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: left;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  padding-left: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
  transition: .3s background-color;
}

.nav a:hover {
  background-color: #005f5f;
}

.nav a.active {
  background-color: #aaa;
  color: #444;
  cursor: default;
}

/* Sub Menus */
.nav li li {
  font-size: .8em;
}

/*******************************************
   Style menu for larger screens

   Using 650px (130px each * 5 items), but ems
   or other values could be used depending on other factors
********************************************/

@media screen and (min-width: 650px) {
  .nav li {
    width: 130px;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 50px;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: -4px;
  }

  .nav a {
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .nav > ul > li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .nav > ul > li > a {
    padding-left: 0;
  }

  /* Sub Menus */
  .nav li ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: none;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: grey;
  }

  .nav li:hover ul {
    display: block;
  }

  .nav li ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
  }
}
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/oyw6rnu8/1/)

Comment: Thanks brother Beckett. Actually i am a fresher and i dont have much knowledge of front end development. thanks for the help.

Comment: i want to ask one more question ? i want to hide the drop down menu on click on the link which are under the drop down menu

Comment: @Mubashir could you explain a little more about what you want and I'll be able to help you out?