# Why isnt this drop down populating with working links?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am studying bootstrap by making changes to examples.  The drop down menu that I am trying to create should have three links.  The main tab should link to `someroute`, while the two links that are revealed by the drop down menu should let users click to `route3` and `route4` respectively.  But instead there is a dead link where there should be three working links.  **What specific changes need to be made to the code below to make all four links in the menu bar work, including the three in the drop down?**

Here is [a plnkr that recreates the problem including the code below](http://plnkr.co/edit/T96QWX1uEccH34l2Ievt?p=preview).

Here is index.html, which includes the bootstrap code for the drop down menu:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>  
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.20/angular-route.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <style type="text/css">
    [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak { display: none !important; }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body class="ng-cloak" ng-cloak="" ng-app="hello">
    <div class="container" ng-controller="navigation">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" role="tablist">
            <li ng-class="{active:tab('home')}"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
                <a ng-class="{active:tab('someroute')}" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="/someroute">Some route
                <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li ng-class="{active:tab('route3')}"><a href="/route3">route three</a></li>
                    <li ng-class="{active:tab('route4')}"><a href="/route4">route four</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="container" ng-view=""></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="home.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="someroute.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="navigation.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Bootstrap's JS files in your example, and also JQuery, which is required by bootstrap... try adding the following to your `<head>`:

```
<script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: This change, in addition to adding `#` as suggested by another user's deleted answer, solved the problem.  See updated plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/T96QWX1uEccH34l2Ievt?p=preview

Comment: Are you willing to comment on how to get the drop down to appear on hover instead of just on click?  That would save a separate posting.  Thank you and +1.

Comment: Sure, seems bootstrap doesn't support it by default, but the first answer here gives a pretty simple solution to do it yourself:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here:

1. You are using `html5Mode` on plnkr.co, which in my experience doesn't work with routing because the app preview is served in an iframe
2. You are including Bootstrap's CSS but not its JavaScript (for Angular, you want to use [UI Bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) instead)
3. When using UI Bootstrap, you need to use the custom directives `uib-dropdown`, `uib-dropdown-toggle`, and `uib-dropdown-menu` instead of those classes, because Angular uses directives to deal with DOM elements, not class selectors

Here is a working example: [plnkr.co](http://embed.plnkr.co/2pYFk0BKhn5p2cPQvN26/)