# how to make bootstrap 3 dropdown on hover and click? (using in nav, not navbar)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap 3 for desktop, and only using nav, rather than navbar.
How to make a dropdown on hover and click?

```html
<ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#">menuA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuB</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuC</a>
        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menuD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap Dropdown with Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214326/bootstrap-dropdown-with-hover)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With this simple CSS.

```css
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#">menuA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuB</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuC</a>
        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menuD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: first level owrked but not wokring on second level

Comment: Love the simplicity (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Use this script, since you are using `jquery` for `bootstrap` anyway. Also give additional `classes` (preferably `ids`) to jquery selector so it doesn't affect other dropdowns in your page .

```js
$(function(){
  $("#nav .dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('#products-menu.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $('#products-menu.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#">menuA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuB</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuC</a>
        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menuD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuE</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Above solutions are not mobile friendly so here is the solution I am proposing

Detect if its not touch device and that the `navbar-toggle` (hamburger menu) is not visible and make the menu item hoverable

Also made tne margin-top 0 because the gap between the navbar and the menu in some browser will not let you hover to the subitems

As a **bonus** you can make the menu parent link clickable by uncommenting the commented line

```js
$(function(){
    function is_touch_device() {
        return 'ontouchstart' in window        // works on most browsers 
        || navigator.maxTouchPoints;       // works on IE10/11 and Surface
    };

    if(!is_touch_device() && $('.navbar-toggle:hidden')){
      $('.dropdown-menu', this).css('margin-top',0);
      $('.dropdown').hover(function(){ 
          $('.dropdown-toggle', this).trigger('click');
          //uncomment below to make the parent item clickable
          //$('.dropdown-toggle', this).toggleClass("disabled"); 
      });   
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#">menuA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuB</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuC</a>
        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menuD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuE</a></li>
</ul>
```

```js
$(function(){
  $("#nav .dropdown").hover(
    function() {
      $('#products-menu.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    },
    function() {
      $('#products-menu.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).fadeOut("fast");
      $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<ul id="nav" class="nav nav-pills clearfix right" role="tablist">
    <li><a href="#">menuA</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuB</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">menuC</a>
        <ul id="products-menu" class="dropdown-menu clearfix" role="menu">
            <li><a href="">A</a></li>
            <li><a href="">B</a></li>
            <li><a href="">C</a></li>
            <li><a href="">D</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menuD</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuE</a></li>
</ul>
```