# Disable dropdown on hover for bootstrap when navbar is collapsed

Tags: drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have implemented the css as shown here: [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

However want to disable the dropdown on hover when the navbar collapses as it acts a bit buggy.

How can I do it?

Comment: Did you ever find an uncomplicated way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You could try wrapping the CSS to disable the  dropdown in a media query so that it is only disabling it at a certain page width... Reading up on media queries and trying to understand how bootstrap implements them is going to be one the keys to debugging this. Here's what I tried with the previous answer's fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/5544/

```
@media (min-width: 767px) {
 .sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
}
}
```