# bootstrap drop down top level navigation make a clickable link

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I'm using the-bootstrap wordpress theme to create a menu with drop-downs, however the top-level link only reveals the drop-down on clicking & does not go to a page itself when clicked. So in www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/ when I click 'Flooring' I want to go to the flooring page as well as revealing the dropdown.
Code below, thanks in advance

```html
<nav class="subnav clearfix">
  <ul id="menu-product-menu" class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
    <li id="menu-item-87" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-87 dropdown" data-dropdown="dropdown">
      <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=31" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        Flooring <b class="caret"></b>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li id="menu-item-88" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-88 dropdown-submenu" data-dropdown="dropdown">
          <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=32" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Ash Flooring</a>

          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li id="menu-item-82" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-82">
              <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=60">Ash Flooring Gallery</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-89" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-89">
          <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=34">Spruce Flooring</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-90" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-90">
          <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=36">Birch Flooring</a>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-91" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-91">
          <a href="http://www.thermoryuk.co.uk/wp/?page_id=38">Pecan Flooring</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

```js
/* ============================================================
     * bootstrap-dropdown.js v2.2.2
     * http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#dropdowns
     * ============================================================
     * Copyright 2012 Twitter, Inc.
     *
     * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     * You may obtain a copy of the License at
     *
     * http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
     *
     * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     * limitations under the License.
     * ============================================================ */
!function ($) {
  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;
  /* DROPDOWN CLASS DEFINITION
      * ========================= */
  var toggle = '[data-toggle=dropdown]'
  , Dropdown = function (element) {
    var $el = $(element).on('click.dropdown.data-api', this.toggle)
    $('html').on('click.dropdown.data-api', function () {
      $el.parent().removeClass('open')
    })
  }
  Dropdown.prototype = {
    constructor: Dropdown
    , toggle: function (e) {
      var $this = $(this)
      , $parent
      , isActive
      if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return
      $parent = getParent($this)
      isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')
      clearMenus()
      if (!isActive) {
        $parent.toggleClass('open')
      }
      $this.focus()
      return false
    }
    , keydown: function (e) {
      var $this
      , $items
      , $active
      , $parent
      , isActive
      , index
      if (!/(38|40|27)/.test(e.keyCode)) return
      $this = $(this)
      e.preventDefault()
      e.stopPropagation()
      if ($this.is('.disabled, :disabled')) return
      $parent = getParent($this)
      isActive = $parent.hasClass('open')
      if (!isActive || (isActive && e.keyCode == 27)) return $this.click()
      $items = $('[role=menu] li:not(.divider):visible a', $parent)
      if (!$items.length) return
      index = $items.index($items.filter(':focus'))
      if (e.keyCode == 38 && index > 0) index--                                        // up
      if (e.keyCode == 40 && index < $items.length - 1) index++                        // down
      if (!~index) index = 0
      $items
      .eq(index)
      .focus()
    }
  }
  function clearMenus() {
    $(toggle).each(function () {
      getParent($(this)).removeClass('open')
    })
  }
  function getParent($this) {
    var selector = $this.attr('data-target')
    , $parent
    if (!selector) {
      selector = $this.attr('href')
      selector = selector && /#/.test(selector) && selector.replace(/.*(?=#[^\s]*$)/, '') //strip for ie7
    }
    $parent = $(selector)
    $parent.length || ($parent = $this.parent())
    return $parent
  }
  /* DROPDOWN PLUGIN DEFINITION
       * ========================== */
  var old = $.fn.dropdown
  $.fn.dropdown = function (option) {
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this)
      , data = $this.data('dropdown')
      if (!data) $this.data('dropdown', (data = new Dropdown(this)))
      if (typeof option == 'string') data[option].call($this)
        })
  }
  $.fn.dropdown.Constructor = Dropdown
  /* DROPDOWN NO CONFLICT
      * ==================== */
  $.fn.dropdown.noConflict = function () {
    $.fn.dropdown = old
    return this
  }
  /* APPLY TO STANDARD DROPDOWN ELEMENTS
       * =================================== */
  $(document)
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', clearMenus)
  .on('click.dropdown touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown form', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
  .on('touchstart.dropdown.data-api', '.dropdown-menu', function (e) { e.stopPropagation() })
  .on('click.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api'  , toggle, Dropdown.prototype.toggle)
  .on('keydown.dropdown.data-api touchstart.dropdown.data-api', toggle + ', [role=menu]' , Dropdown.prototype.keydown)
}(window.jQuery);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can set that by removing `data-toggle="dropdown"`from your HTML markup. As an addition to your question we can set the dropdown work on mouseover by setting `data-hover="dropdown"`.

Comment: I have gone through the answers of similar question and im sure that no one can beat this answer.....

Comment: How would this work for mobile devices without 'mouseover' events?

Answer (score 3):

That's the [default behaviour](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navs). The nav's are activated by clicks, not hovers. This explains why clicking the anchor, is revealing the submenu instead of following the link.

There's a work around in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click).

Comment: thanks dotty, if I remove the data-toggle from the 'a' tag, it seems to work, my jquery isn't up to much, I tried using $(document).off('.data-api','a'); but nothing doing...

Answer (score 3):

We can simply use that code:

```
$('#sub-nav > ul > li > a').click( function() {

        location.href = $(this).attr('href');

    })
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking into this with Bootstrap 3 and was able to make this work on my project by assigning separate links to the text and the caret span:

```html
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked left-menu" id="sub-nav">
  <li>
    <a href="/schools-departments">Schools &amp; Departments</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-target="#item1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#sub-nav" class="sub-drop"><span class="caret arrow"></span></a>
    <ul class="nav nav-stacked collapse left-submenu" id="item1">
      <li><a href="#">School of Arts &amp; Sciences</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">School of Education &amp; Behavioral Sciences</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">School of Health Sciences</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Then added this to the css:

```css
#sub-nav li a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A little tweak on what was proposed above. Works to Toggle the dropdown menu and tap again when menu is down to follow the parent link

```
<script>
function clickMe(obj){ 
    if($(obj).data('clicked') == 'true'){
        location.href = $(obj).attr('href');
    }
     else{
    $(obj).data('clicked','true');
    }
}
</script>
```

add some html

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="dropdown">
 <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-clicked="false" onclick="clickMe(this);" data-target="#" href="http://www.Add your link here.com">Link#1 <b class="caret"></b></a> 
 <ul class="dropdown-menu">....your drop down list here
```

[js fiddle try it out](https://jsfiddle.net/jombie/9j2dxh1n/2/)

Answer (score 0):

add this css to your navbar

```
<style>
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover ul.dropdown-menu{     display: block;     margin: 0 }
</style>
```

and add attribute

```
onclick="location.href='filename'"

 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" onclick="location.href='filename'" data-toggle="dropdown"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest also testing for the body width, so mobile nav keeps working properly.
So only set location.href, if the body size is bigger than the breakpoint:

```
$('.navbar-collapse a.dropdown-toggle').click(function() {
  if($('body').width() >= "768") {
    location.href = $(this).attr('href');
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Modify A tag like this:

   ```
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-clicked="false" onclick="clickMe(this);"  data-target="#">
   ```
2. On you JS file add:

   ```
   function clickMe(obj){ 
       if($(obj).data('clicked') == 'true'){
           location.href = $(obj).attr('href');
       }
       else {
           $(obj).data('clicked','true');
       }
   }
   ```