# How to provide link to top level anchor tag in bootstrap(v4.1.1) navigation having sub menu?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I want to provide a link to the top level anchor tag in the bootstrap menu. I am using `data-toggle="dropdown"` to the parent anchor tag to open its submenu. but this will disable its `href` link.
How I can provide `href` to the top anchor tag and keep the drop-down menu functionality?

I searched a lot and found a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16731974/bootstrap-drop-down-top-level-navigation-make-a-clickable-link) but I don't want to use jQuery, I also tried `data-hover="dropdown"` property but doesn't help.

HTML Structure:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown menu-item-has-children show">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="about-us.html" target="_blank" id="navbarDropdownBlog" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                            Company Overview
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right show" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="vision-and-values.html">Vision and Values</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="ethics.html">Ethics</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="history.html">History</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="delivery-systems.html">Delivery Systems</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownBlog1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Capabilities
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownBlog1">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="infrastructure.html">Infrastructure</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="building.html">Building</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link" href="all-projects.html">Projects</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="sustainability.html" id="navbarDropdownPortfolio" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            Sustainability
                        </a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownPortfolio">
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="health-and-safety.html">Health &amp; Safety</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="environment.html">Environment</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="community.html">Community</a>
                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="quality.html">Quality</a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Please find the screenshot for HTML structure below:

[image]

Comment: show your code not image(better set it in snippet)

Comment: If you could, please edit  *your actual code* as text into your question - images of code *alone* are [tedious and difficult](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to work with and debug. It forces those who would otherwise love to help you to [transcribe your image](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) first, which is a waste of time.

Comment: @Rishi Jagati when you want to show dropdown on hover?

Comment: what version of bootstrap do u use?

Comment: I want to provide a link to the top level anchor. either on click or hover.

Comment: Using Bootstrap v4.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fixed** by removing the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute from HTML and add css to open drop-down on hover using below css.

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
    display:block;
}
```

**Note**: This fix is for desktop only, NOT for mobile.