# Hide Twitter Bootstrap 3 dropdown on clicking anywhere outside on iPad

Tags: ipad, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I need to hide the dropdown when clicking anywhere outside on iPad.
Also I need to trigger dropdown on hover instead of click.

This is my code so far: http://codepen.io/sushimashi/pen/Hfcse

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem with the click, the dropdowns hide when I click outside (tested in my PC but I think it must work same on iPad). Btw, in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click) you can find the solution about hover in dropdowns.

Comment: Thanks. The behavior doesn't replicate on iPad as far as I have tested. For second question, thanks that does help.