# menu dropdown onhover bootstrap not working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I need to dropdown the menu on over. How do I do it? This is what I tried.

This is my code

```
<nav id="navigation" class="cbp-af-header">
    <div class="container">
        <ul id="menu" >
          <li class="current"><a href="/" >Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="{% url 'product' %}">Product</a></li>
          <li ><a href="{% url 'services' %}">Services</a></li>
          <li class="dropdown" id="get_started"> 
             <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Get Started <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
               <li><a href="{% url 'request_demo' %}">Demo the Platform</a></li>
           </ul>
         </li>
       </ul>
   </div>
 </nav>
```

Here is jquery

```
$('#menu li').hover(function () {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').toggle();
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Comment: I've tried this, but to no luck. I've read many threads on SO's but neither of them succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use CSS

```
#menu li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```