# Bootstrap hover tabs showing multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've used the answer from this question '[How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)'

The problem is that when the mouse is moved quickly over all tabs, multiple .tab-pane elements are displayed in the tab-content element.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VPn52/)

HTML

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li class="active"><a href="#tab1">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab2">Profile</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab3">Messages</a></li>
  <li><a href="#tab4">Account</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab1">
      TAB1 CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab2">
      TAB2 OTHER CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab3">
      TAB3 MORE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane fade active" id="tab4">
      TAB4 SO MUCH CONTENT
  </div>  
</div>
```

JS

```
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseover( function(){
    $(this).find('a').tab('show');
});
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
  $(this).find('a').tab('hide');
});
```

Move the mouseX across the tabs rapidly back and forth and sometimes you will see both at once:

TAB1 CONTENT

TAB2 OTHER CONTENT

In my actual version you don't have to move as fast for the problem to occur.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's the because the `fade` class in bootstrap is an animation. If you move fast enought, the first one hasn't finished before the second one starts. Change the HTML:

```
<div class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="tab1">
      TAB1 CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
      TAB2 OTHER CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
      TAB3 MORE CONTENT
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="tab4">
      TAB4 SO MUCH CONTENT
  </div>  
</div>
```

Updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VPn52/1/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Any way I could keep the animation? Maybe check for any other active tabs and hide them?

Comment: Not sure, bootstrap's `fade` is a CSS transition: `opacity: 0;-webkit-transition: opacity .15s linear;transition: opacity .15s linear;`, and I don't really know what to do to interrupt one of those in a controlled fashion. Maybe if you write your own fading animation using jquery you can use it's queueing or chaining mechanisms.

Answer (score 3):

maybe you can try my solution. 
i try this solution in my code and it works. 
for hover solution, i follow solution from here:
http://tutsme-webdesign.info/bootstrap-3-toggable-tabs-and-pills/

```
jQuery('.nav-tabs a').hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(this).tab('show');
});
```

add this line (line 3 or after .. e.preventDefault(); .. )

```
jQuery('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
tabContentSelector = jQuery(this).attr('href');
```

and this line (after .. jQuery(this).tab('show') .. )

```
jQuery(tabContentSelector).addClass('active');
```

so the code become like this:

```
jQuery('.nav-tabs a').hover(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery('.tab-pane').removeClass('active');
    tabContentSelector = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery(this).tab('show');
    jQuery(tabContentSelector).addClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could also do, if you want to keep the fading effect, is have a boolean to keep track of whether a tab is currently fading in, to prevent others from being triggered, this should work:

```
var tabFadingIn = false;
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseover( function(){
  var $tab = $(this).find('a');
  if (!tabFadingIn) {
    tabFadingIn = true;
    $tab.one('shown.bs.tab', function() {
      tabFadingIn = false;
    });
    $tab.tab('show');
  }
});
$('.nav-tabs > li').mouseout( function(){
  $(this).find('a').tab('hide');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found sollution for me. 
Default speed of fade animation is 0.15s. You need to reduse it to 0.1s. Now another picture don’t have time to appear before first disappear.