# Wordpress navagation menu, sub nav drop down on hover instead of on click

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, css

I am having a problem with my site: http://tinyurl.com/lc4ewwf

I want the Navigation Menu to display the Sub Menu when you hover over it. At the moment it only displays when you click on it. What would be the best solution to achieve this?

I was just going to install a plugin called ubermenu to replace the current one, but this WordPress theme is out of date, and that solution wouldn't work.

Comment: Maybe a CSS Solution: `#menu-top-menu li:hover ul {display: block;}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your issue resides in the Twitter Boostrap dropdown script.. it works on click by default. here is a solution on SO: [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 0):

use this i tested through console it is working fine.

```
jQuery('.dropdown-menu').parent().hover(function(){
    jQuery('.dropdown-menu').parent().removeClass('open');
    jQuery(this).addClass('open');
}, function(){
    jQuery(this).removeClass('open');
});
```