# After fixing open menu on mouseover in bootstrap3.0, when we click on menuitem the menu is not closing it remain opened

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have set up a navbar with some dropdown menus in it (using `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"`), and it works fine.

The thing is it works `onClick`, while I would prefer if it worked `onHover`.

Is there any built-in way to do this?

I tried this

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu
{
   display: block;
}
```

this works fine menu will open on mouse over, but problem is when we click on any menu item it will not close menu will be kept opened, menu should be closed after we click on any menu item.

Comment: possible dublicate [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 0):

Answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click) question, maybe a possible duplicate

**CSS:**

```
.sidebar-nav {
    padding: 9px 0;
}

.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
    left: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu li:hover .sub-menu {
    visibility: visible;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}

.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 0;
}

.navbar .sub-menu:before {
    border-bottom: 7px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 7px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    border-top: 7px solid transparent;
    left: -7px;
    top: 10px;
}
.navbar .sub-menu:after {
    border-top: 6px solid transparent;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 6px solid #fff;
    border-bottom: 6px solid transparent;
    left: 10px;
    top: 11px;
    left: -6px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/3100/)

### OR

Simply use this plugin [Bootstrap: Dropdown on Hover Plugin](http://cameronspear.com/demos/bootstrap-hover-dropdown/)

Comment: just remove the css part from demo, than check clicking on any menuitem will close the menu itself. same behavior i am trying to achieve with hover.

Comment: Sorry, I can't use any plugin.