# Hover on Bootstrap Navbar using CSS, how to handle gap between dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

I follow this link [1] to open my dropdown when mouse is over, basically I added

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

The work fine, but the problem is what if I want the dropdown menu to have some vertical gap between the menu item?

```
.nav-tabs .dropdown-menu, .nav-pills .dropdown-menu, .navbar .dropdown-menu {
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}
```

The issue is when the mouse is out of menu item, the dropdown will be closed manually. I guess this can only be done by JS with some delay?

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/5438/

[1] [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hacky but it works. Add invisible block above .dropdown-menu block

```
.dropdown-menu:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    height: 25px;
    top: -25px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/5440/)

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it without JS by adding a wrapper class around the submenu like [this.](http://jsfiddle.net/2Smgv/5439/) In addition you have to remove the `margin-top:20px`