# How to make bootstrap dropdown works on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make bootstrap dropdown to work with hover on resolution greater than 767px.

I saw this SO Question [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click), which suggesting this

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

But the problem is, I have to disable the click effect, only on resolution greater than 767px. Ie below this resolution (especially in mobile devices), it has to work on click which the bootstrap usually does.

**What i tried so far**

make the css to this

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu,
ul.nav li.dropdown:active > ul.dropdown-menu 
{
    display: block;    
}
```

and change the

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"/>
```

to

```
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle=""/>
```

Now it disable the click in resolution > 767px, 
and also works the click event on resolution < 767px
here the problem is that it doesn't work that perfectly like before on resolution < 767px.

It's the closest I can come, any help can be appreciated.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click?rq=1

Comment: Do you realize that there are tablets/phablets that are touch-only and >=768px wide? Your premise is flawed, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

you can wrap your css code with media query:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
        display: block;    
    }
}
```

**To disable click:**

```
$('.nav .dropdown > a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: its already fine with > 768px, I need it work in < 768,
also by doing this, how can we disable click event even in this resolution??

Comment: I don't get you, if you can work it out for resolution above 767px why you can't on below?

Comment: then how can i disable the click event, I think my question was not clear for you.