# Bootstrap: Remake jQuery function to work on hover instead of click

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap and got stuck.
The code below works on click. How can I remake it so it would work on hover? I'm a noob in jQuery..

```
$(document)
.on('click.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
  var $btn = $(e.target)
  if (!$btn.hasClass('btn')) $btn = $btn.closest('.btn')
  Plugin.call($btn, 'toggle')
  e.preventDefault()
})
.on('focus.bs.button.data-api blur.bs.button.data-api', '[data-toggle^="button"]', function (e) {
  $(e.target).closest('.btn').toggleClass('focus', /^focus(in)?$/.test(e.type))
})
}(jQuery);
```

p.s. It seems like the important string is '[data-toggle^="button"]', since deleting this ruins the functionality
p.p.s. I've already read [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click) but it didn't help. I'd prefer not to ruin what I'v already done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy solution, is to make CSS

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, as this triggers the right events in Bootstrap: dropdown.js v3.3.7

```
<script>
    $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
        $(this).find('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown('toggle');
    });
</script>
```