# Bootstrap: on hover in Dropdown menu parent menu highlighted

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> i found solution here :  http://www.smartmenus.org/

I am using bootstrap fixed `nav`, I customized it a bit so that instead of clicking menu when someone hover over the menu sub it will be displayed.

This is the code I added:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

and this is the structure of the HTML:

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" 
       class="dropdown-toggle" 
       data-toggle="dropdown" 
       role="button"  
       arial-expanded="false"> Top Menu
    </a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
    <li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
    <li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When hovered over parent menu it displays bottom menu but when I go to sub menu parent menu hover state is gone, it should be selected in that situation. Can someone please help me how to implement it in bootstrap 3.0

Comment: Well for one you closing the `</li>` before closing the `</ul>` should be the other way around. Not that this is a cause for the error, but something I noticed.

Comment: Also remove that spacing between your `<` and `li` in all your links. Should be: `<li><a href=".."></a></li>`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 2):

Try it with JavaScript:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');        
        },
        function() {
            $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
            $(this).toggleClass('open');       
        }
    );
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<li class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button"  arial-expanded="false">Top Menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
<li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
<li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
<li><a href="submenu.php">submenu</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
```