# bootstrap dropdown won't hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

1. I am new in bootstrap,the dropdown won't hide, i want dropdown when
   i hover on the link, but its show always, advance thanks to
   everyone. here is the code

                       `<nav>
                           <ul class="nav navbar-nav main-navigation">
                               <li><a href="">HOME</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">BLOG</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">PAGES</a></li>
                               <li><a href="">FEATURES</a></li>
                               <li role="presentation" class="dropdown">
                               <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false">MEGA MENU</a>
                                   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                       <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                       <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                  </ul>
                               </li>
                               <li><a href="">CONTACT</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </nav>`

Comment: Duplicate question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Comment: do you even have any css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use Jquery:
https://jsfiddle.net/2w4n7pho/

```
<script>
    $(function(){
    $("li.dropdown").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("open");
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Bootstrap (3.0+) dropdown menu only appears/disappears on click. This behavior would need to be overruled through CSS or JS. If you want to simply have the dropdown appear on hover while preserving the click to drop down functionality on mobile, something like this should suffice:

```
ul.nav li.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu {
    display: block;    
}
```

Demonstration: http://www.bootply.com/tpCO1Nb4E8

Comment: It does work, as demonstrated here: http://www.bootply.com/tpCO1Nb4E8. Looks like you have other issues interfering with the default bootstrap functionality.