# How to make the navi bar aligned in HTML5 (bootstrap)?

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B20POVCV692nckVLQUZCTkFIRFk/view?usp=sharing

The website name and search stays on one line but all the others are on another line. How to make them in one line?

My code is as follows:

```
<div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
</div>

<form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form> 

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: You mean you want to put the navigation bar on the top of the webpage? What do you mean by 'others are on another line'? not quite understand..

Comment: I think you need see this link **[Bootstrap Menu][1]**

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Comment: [Please try to improve your spelling.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291362)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="navbar-header">

</div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
           <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    <span class="icon-bar"></span>                        
  </button>
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>



  </ul>

  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <form class="navbar-form" role="search" style="float:left;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form> 
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
    <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
  </ul>
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sL7sdv1u/