# Modifying Dropdown-Toggle for Hover

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am attempting to modify the [Moderna](http://bootstraptaste.com/theme/moderna/)  site template. If you look at the links in the header and click on `Features` you will see a dropdown menu.

What I am trying to do is change it so this menu appears on `hover` instead of on `click` but I cannot seem to get it working.

These are what I am changing in the...

HTML

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse ">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown active">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-delay="0" data-close-others="false">Features <b class=" icon-angle-down"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="typography.html">Typography</a></li>
                <li><a href="components.html">Components</a></li>
                <li><a href="pricingbox.html">Pricing box</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="blog.html">Blog</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
header .nav li a:hover,
header .nav li a:focus,
header .nav li.active a,
header .nav li.active a:hover,
header .nav li a.dropdown-toggle:hover,
header .nav li a.dropdown-toggle:focus,
header .nav li.active ul.dropdown-menu li a:hover,
header .nav li.active ul.dropdown-menu li.active a{
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    -o-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
}
```

I have tried changing the `class="dropdown-toggle"` to

- `class="dropdown-toggle:hover"`
- `class="hover"`
- `class="dropdown-toggle hover"`

and I have tried changing `data-toggle="dropdown"` to

- `data-toggle="dropdown hover"`
- `data-toggle="hover"`
- `data-toggle="dropdown-toggle:hover"`

but to no avail. I am doing something wrong however, I am not knowledgeable (clearly) enough to figure it out.

Comment: Might be related to this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Comment: Hmmmm. I was looking at my css and I have changed almost all of the ones that just say `dropdown-toggle` to `dropdown-toggle:hover` but changing it either breaks my code or does no change. Per one of the comments I have also just tried removing `class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"` and that broke it also.

Comment: Using :hover pseudoclass won't work. I'm trying to figure out how is this menu even displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the behavior that you expect not to be managed via css but rather via javascript and then change the class name is not needed. In this case, the click event that is caught and handled to display the menu.