# Bootstrap Navbar Dropdown Menu Background Color & Activate on Hover

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navigation, navbar

I would like to make it so that the navbar dropdown menu activates on hover and for it to change the background color of the dropdown menu "button" when activated.

Here is my html for the navbar:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-trans navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <!-- Container makes the navbar extend across the whole screen, removing the default curved sides -->
  <div class="container">
  <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-collapsible">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Pandora</a>
    </div>
<!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <% if defined?(Devise) %>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Account <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Edit Account", edit_user_registration_path %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Sign Out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete %></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Login", new_user_session_path %></li>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign Up", new_user_registration_path %></li>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- container-collapse -->
</nav>
```

Thank you very much. Let me know if you would like me to clarify anything at all.

Comment: Look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Answer (score 1):

For the first problem  - navbar dropdown menu to activate on hover- check the link from vanburenx.

If you want to change the background color of the dropdown menu -

```
ul.dropdown-menu{
  background-color: tomato;
```

}

Comment: It is still white backgrounf when I click on the dropdown. But the correct color when I hover. Do you know what it could be?