# How enable Hover event for bootstrap menus?

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, hover, mousehover

I implement a bootstrap responsive rich menu and it works fine.
It works on Click event ,my question is :  How can I change it to Hover event ?
all bootstrap menus have this issue . bootstrap doesn't have any support for this ? 
this is the menu I use :
http://geedmo.github.io/yamm/ 
my problem solved with :

```
<style>
    li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
        display: block;
    }

    li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle {
        color: #555;
        background-color: #e5e5e5;
    }
</style>
```

but a new problem happened , the submenus showed in the end of the menus when I shrink the browser   [image: showed in the end of the menu] , and it's not appropriate :/

Comment: checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click?rq=1

Comment: I search all the stackoverflow and I don't found it , Thanks a lot @HarshanaSamaranayaka

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this style to your page.

```
<style>
    li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{display:block}
    li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-toggle{color:#555; background-color:#e5e5e5}
</style>
```

First one will enable dropdown on mouse hover and second one will change the menu header color (choose the appropriate color for your page).

Comment: Thank you  very much  , it works perfect :) @svjn

Comment: it works fine , thanks a lot but , excuse me , when I shrink the browser , submenus shows in end of the menu , can you help me again how I solve it ? @svjn

Answer (score 1):

Try with this HTML, JS and CSS

CSS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
function navbarSubmenu(width) {
   if (width > 767) {
    $('.navbar-custom .navbar-nav > li.dropdown').hover(function() {
     var MenuLeftOffset  = $('.dropdown-menu', $(this)).offset().left;
     var Menu1LevelWidth = $('.dropdown-menu', $(this)).width();
     if (width - MenuLeftOffset < Menu1LevelWidth * 2) {
      $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').addClass('leftauto');
     } else {
      $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('leftauto');
     }
     if ($('.dropdown', $(this)).length > 0) {
      var Menu2LevelWidth = $('.dropdown-menu', $(this)).width();
      if (width - MenuLeftOffset - Menu1LevelWidth < Menu2LevelWidth) {
       $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').addClass('left-side');
      } else {
       $(this).children('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('left-side');
      }
     }
    });
   }
  }
  });
```

```css
.navbar-custom .dropdown-toggle:after {
position: absolute;
display: block;
right: 0;
top: 50%;
margin-top: -6px;
font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
font-size: 9px;
content: "\f107";
text-rendering: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu{display:block}
  .navbar-custom .open > .dropdown-menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
  } 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<nav class="navbar navbar-custom navbar-transparent navbar-fixed-top one-page" role="navigation">
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" id="custom-collapse" aria-expanded="true">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right mnCh">

    
     <li class="current">
      <a href="/#" title="Home">Home</a>
      
     </li>
    
     <li class="link">
      <a href="/#" title="About us">About us</a>
      
     </li>
    
     <li class="link dropdown">
      <a href="/#" title="Collection" class="dropdown-toggle binded" data-toggle="dropdown">Collection</a>
      
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        
         <li><a href="/#">Collection 1</a></li>
        
         <li><a href="/#">Collection 2</a></li>
        
         <li><a href="/#">Collection 3</a></li>
        
         <li><a href="/#">Collection 4</a></li>
        
       </ul>
      
     </li> 
     <li class="link">
      <a href="/#" title="Store">Store</a>
      
     </li>
    
     <li class="link dropdown">
      <a href="/#" title="Press &amp; News" class="dropdown-toggle binded" data-toggle="dropdown">Press &amp; News</a>
      
       <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        
         <li><a href="/#">Press</a></li>
        
         <li><a href="/#">News</a></li>
        
       </ul>
      
     </li>
    
     <li class="link">
      <a href="/#" title="Download">Download</a>
      
     </li>
    

    <li class="dropdown">
     <a href="/#" class="dropdown-toggle binded" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Languages
     </a>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
       
      <li><a href="/en">English</a></li>
      <li><a href="/it">Italiano</a></li>
       
     </ul>
    </li>

   </ul>
  </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: thanks , it's a cool menu . I correct Hover , but submenus shows in end of the all menus like the picture I posted . I don't know how fix it . @MaGio

Comment: The css is a media query for mobile view, and js replace the bootstrap submenu css option. i've test it and the submenu open inside.