# href not working on dropdown-toggle - bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I fail to understand why `href` is not working on `a` tag for `data-toggle="dropdown"` . When I hit the `Lists` tab, i should be routed to the `google` website.

[FIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/c2uydfhr/)

Simple HTML:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Lists</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @unicorn2 no its not working in my local environment

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From Bootstrap documentation [(http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)):

> To keep URLs intact with link buttons, use the data-target attribute
>   instead of href="#".

So your code should be

```
 <a data-target="http://www.google.es"  target="_blank" href="http://www.google.es" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle">Lists</a>

<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Sub List 2</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Futhermore, you can find more information about how to get menu dropdown using hover instead of click: [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Comment: Can I update the URL on the same page and not open a new tab?

Comment: Yes, I used target="_blank" because in fiddle doesn't work the iframe. Only remove target attribute.

Comment: You also should remove `data-toggle="dropdown"`. Then it will work well. (Tested on Bootstrap 4.4.1)

Answer (score 10):

A simple jQuery solution:

```
$('#menu-main > li > .dropdown-toggle').click(function () {
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

But the better solution is to replace the `data-toggle` attribute with `data-hover`

So your final code will be:

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <a href="http://google.com" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-hover="dropdown">Lists</a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 1</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">Sub List 2</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Happy to help @BartSabayton! If you think it's appropriate, please mark this answer as the accepted solution.

Answer (score 1):

Remove: data-toggle="dropdown"
It's work for me.