# Bootstrap top level item clickable and open dropdown on hover

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the yamm3 menu and I would like the top level menu items clickable and then show the dropdown on hover.

I'm using the following code to make the dropdown on hover instead of on click:

```js
$('.navbar .dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(250).slideDown();
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').first().stop(true, true).delay(100).slideUp()
});
```

But I still having trouble getting to top menu items to be clickable.

Here is the HTML

```html
 <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">About Us<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Meet Our Team</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Why GoPlay </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Affiliations </a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Contact US </a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>           
            <li class="dropdown yamm-fw"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Browse Tours<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li>
                  <div class="yamm-content">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Soccer" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Soccer</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Rugby" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Rugby</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Volleyball" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Volleyball</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Field Hockey" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Field Hockey</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Basketball" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Basketball</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Baseball and Softball" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Baseball/Sofatball</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Other Sports" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Other Sports</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Tournaments" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Tournaments</div>
                      <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-2"><a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img alt="Fan Tours" src="images/placeholder_browsetours_dropdown.png"></a><br/>Fan Tours</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Coaches<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Sports Philosophy</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Five Steps Planning Your Tour </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> What to Expect </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Benefits </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Service Guarantee </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> What to Expect Overseas</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Download Coaches Handbook</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li> 
            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Players<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Travel With GoPlay</a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> What to Pack </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Making Payments </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Automatic Payments </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Protection Plans </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> Keeping in Touch </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> GoPlay Travel App </a></li>
                <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#"> FAQ </a></li>                
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="no-dropdown"><a href="#"> Flights </a></li>
            <li class="no-dropdown"><a href="#"> Blog </a></li>                       
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please include the HTML as well in your question and take a look at [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: for bootstrap-examples maybe use: bootply.com

Answer (score 0):

you have to delete the data-toggle="dropdown" on your top-level-items. otherwise it won't work. and i would suggest to use CSS-only for the dropdown-onhover.

therefore possible duplicate of this: [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 0):

Since I had a bunch of other code that needs to normally run in a non-dropdown-hoverable component, I solved this issue by utilizing the native events in bootstraps dropdown.js.  The solution found in the other thread which utilized css would **not** work in my case.

Below is my solution which is a bit more verbose since I added a timer for visibility and hidden states.  If that's removed, the solution is probably close to 8 lines of code.

---

```
export default class DropdownHover extends Dropdown {

constructor(...args){
    super(...args)

    this.timerIn = null;
    this.timerOut = null;

    this.inTime = 250
    this.outTime = 100

}

config(isInitialized){
    super.config(isInitialized)
    if(isInitialized) return

    var button = this.$()
    button.hover(this.mouseIn.bind(this), this.mouseOut.bind(this))

    this.dropdown = this.$()

}

mouseIn(){
    if(this.timerIn) {
        clearTimeout(this.timerIn);
        this.timerIn = null

        // If there are any gaps between the dropdown
        // and the menu this will fix it
        clearTimeout(this.timerOut);
        this.timerOut = null
    }

    this.timerIn = setTimeout(() => {
        this.dropdown
            .addClass('open')
            .trigger($.Event('shown.bs.dropdown')) // If you look in dropdown.js this is the event used to trigger other actions.
    }, this.inTime)
}

mouseOut(){
    if(this.timerOut) {
        clearTimeout(this.timerOut);
        this.timerOut = null
    }
    this.timerOut = setTimeout(() => {
        this.dropdown
            .removeClass('open')
            .trigger($.Event('hidden.bs.dropdown'))
    }, this.outTime)
}
}
```