# Bootstrap fixed-top navbar with jquery hover menu tab drops

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I'm learning how to use bootstrap framework on building the website. And there is a navbar hover effect I'd like to replicate. Please see the example below that provided by bootstrap.
https://www.aceandtate.com/
The effect is: The menu texts always show while the nav bar only drops when your mouse over the nav-bar container area.
[Navbar white unfold drops while mouse hover](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQzmw.jpg)

Can anyone show me how to do that?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Answer (score 1):

First, create your dropdown with bootstrap. (I assume you have index.html,css folder, and js folder in one folder). index.html where you use bootstrap to create dropdown menu.

[image: ScreenCap]

in your js folder, edit (create if none) your script.js file.
Add this script

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
    $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

After that, include that script (if not yet include in your html file)

```
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

I place it before

```
</body>
```

Now your dropdown menu will automatic show when you hover the mouse

[image: Hover]

Source : http://codepen.io/betdream/pen/frDqh

Comment: While this may answer the question. It's always recommended to provide answers which are not link only answers. You should consider posting some relevant codes/data in your answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for replying. But the effect from the website is not bootstrap hover dropdown. I added a screen shot in my original posts for further elaboration. Thanks!

Comment: @Aditya Thanks (y)
Here how you do it. Hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for on menu dropdown hover:

> Add this JS:

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
    }, function() {
      $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
    });
```

If you want to show menu always open in mobile device then add media query in your CSS file and set property `display:block`

For media query check this for your reference
[MEDIA QUERIES FOR COMMON DEVICE](https://responsivedesign.is/develop/browser-feature-support/media-queries-for-common-device-breakpoints)