# Trigger bootstraps collapse function on mouseover event

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for a navigation and want to open the collapsed menu not just on a button click but already when hovering the button.
I can't even find the javascript code for the already programmed clicked events.

That's the button to open the navigation:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-target="#main-nav" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="false">
```

That's the navigation to be opened:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
<div id="main-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse" aria-expanded="false" style="height: 2px;">
<div class="container">
```

**My problem:**

I don't know how to deal with bootstrap ( couldn't find in the documentation ) to use hover on the button to open the navbar.

Code when the navigation is not collapsed:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#main-nav" data-toggle="collapse" aria-expanded="true">

<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top in">
<div id="main-nav" class="navbar-collapse collapse in" aria-expanded="true" style="">
<div class="container">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 with-sub">
<li class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 with-sub">
```

Comment: Hey Dennis, I hardly understand your problem: you just want to open a menu when hovering a button? Can you give us a link to the website?

Comment: yes i want to open the menu whem hovering the button, but also the click event. and the website isnt online yet

Comment: But you actually know how to use jQuery hover event? Something like $('button.navbar-toggle').on('hover', function(){
// somethings happening here
})

Comment: yep. but i think im getting in conflict with the other bootstrap events.

Comment: I'd love to see an example of this and to better understand you... too bad it's not online yet. Maybe quickly recreate in jsfiddle?

Comment: dont know if it would be legal to share the code :P since its a project for a company im workin for. maybe i can give u the acces to the website in private

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107214/discussion-between-tonsenson-and-dennis-schutz).

Comment: Probably a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click?

Comment: @dennisschütz Also please try to improve your writing the next time :) (or at least don't be lazy and add apostrophes) (already edited your post, I needs to be approved)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible and quick made up solution would be [jQuery on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) combined with [jQuery trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) function.

```
$('button.navbar-toggle.collapsed').on('mouseenter', function(){
  $(this).trigger('click');
})
```