# Bootstrap dropdown - hover and click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, dropdown

So basically I have this code:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li class="dropdown open">
    <a href="/site.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">Site A</a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <div class="page-width-normal">
            <li class="dd-block main-block">

                <a href="/site.html" class="visible-xs">
                <h4>Title 1</h4>

                </a>                           
                <a href="/site2.html">
                 <h4>Title< 2/h4>

                </a>
                <a href="/site3.html">
                <h4>Title 3</h4>

                </a>
                <a href="/site4.html">
                <h4>Private Placement</h4>

                </a>
            </li>
        </div>
        </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="site5.html">Site 5</a></li>
<li><a href="site6.html">Site 6</a></li>

</ul>
```

The idea is that the first menu in the navbar (Site A) can be expanded on hover, where a dropdown appears. But if the user clicks the link it should lead him to site.html.

However, currently, when I click the Site A link, it opens the dropdown and stays open until I click again.

Another problem is, if I go to mobile view, the user should be able to click Site A link, and it would then show the dropdown menu.

Comment: I'm aware of "disabled" class solves that, but It won't then allow expanding on mobile view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make twitter bootstrap menu dropdown on hover rather than click](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)