# Make hover mouse effect with dropdown-menu

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to improve my `HTML part` from my `Django website` and especially my `Bootstrap navbar tab`. Up to now, I have some `dropdown-submenus` and I have to click on one tab in order to access to the next menu, then submenu.

I would like to get hover effect in order to point my mouse on the tab and without click, get the menu and submenu.

For example, one of my HTML tab looks like :

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> 
        Tables Annuelles & Décennales 
        <b class="caret"></b>
    </a>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span> 
                Edition Tables annuelles
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url "annuel" %}">Naissances</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Reconnaissances</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Mariages</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Décès</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>

        <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> 
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></span> 
                Edition Tables décennales
            </a>

            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Naissances</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Reconnaissances</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Mariages</a></li>
                <li><a href="{% url "BCnotfound" %}">Décès</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And I have a javascript part which looks like :

```
    (function($){
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').on('click', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault(); 
                event.stopPropagation(); 
                $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('open');
                $(this).parent().toggleClass('open');
            });
        });
    })(jQuery);
```

Where I have to modify elements in order to get hover effect on my navbar tab ?

Thank you

Comment: You could try swapping the 'click' with 'mouseenter'

Comment: Works fine ! And if I want to add hover effect directly from my tab and not from dropdown-menu, I have to change `ul.dropdown-menu` by `li.dropdown-toggle` right ?

Comment: Isn't this a dup of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click

Comment: @ZimSystem Thank you ! I'm looking How I can do it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Make this small change..

`$('ul.dropdown-menu [data-toggle=dropdown]').hover(function(event) {`

Comment: Doesn't work because I can't access to my `dropdown-menu`. I can display dropdown-menu but not access to it with my mouse ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu"> --> change to <ul class="navbar-nav">
  <li class="dropdown dropdown-submenu">
```

After that, you can try below. I hope this will work.

```
.navbar-nav li.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```