# How to make hover effect instead of click in bootstrap 4 dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to make hover effect instead of click in bootstrap dropdown menu?

Previous answers don't contain jquery code that you can just past into you own script and get a great result. Apart from this, previous answers wrote for old version bootstrap, and for bootstrap 4 they don't work. For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click) too old, + current question contain a small piece of code which will work for all.

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active uppercase" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle uppercase  outline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase aboutUs" href="#">About us</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Company</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Our process</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Services</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Contact us</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase FAQ" href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click)

Comment: @MasterYoda - That question only addresses v3 and below as of 7/18/2018

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a mouse over event using jquery and apply the same styles and properties that the click event adds..

```js
$( ".dropdown-menu" ).css('margin-top',0);
$( ".dropdown" )
  .mouseover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass('show').attr('aria-expanded',"true");
    $( this ).find('.dropdown-menu').addClass('show');
  })
  .mouseout(function() {
    $( this ).removeClass('show').attr('aria-expanded',"false");
    $( this ).find('.dropdown-menu').removeClass('show');
  });
```

```html
<head>
  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>


      <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active uppercase" href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle uppercase  outline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase aboutUs" href="#">About us</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Company</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Our process</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Services</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Contact us</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item uppercase FAQ" href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

A work around to prevent the menu being hidden after the mouse out is to set margin-top:0 to the dropdown-menu

Comment: Already updated the answer...

Answer (score 2):

Just triggering the click event on `hover()` will do the trick:

```js
$('.nav-link').hover(function() {
    $(this).trigger('click');
}, function() { });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active uppercase" href="#">Home</a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle uppercase  outline" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pages</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase aboutUs" href="#">About us</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Company</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Our process</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase" href="#">Contact us</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item uppercase FAQ" href="#">F.A.Q.</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```