# How to display dropdown menu and submenu items by hover not clicking

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

How can I show dropdown menu items on hovering not on clicking

Here I have about menu dropdown its displaying upon clicking but i want to making it to display menu items on hovering. Same thing should about to sub-menu items aswell. Please let me know if i am missing something

Html

```
<header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top bs-docs-nav" role="banner">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".bs-navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="./" class="navbar-brand">Bootstrap Menu</a>
    </div>
    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse" role="navigation">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Products</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

CSS

```
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Open+Sans';
.navbar-brand {
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase
}

.navbar .nav {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  font-size: 1.2rem
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-color: #003300
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #002200
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  background-color: #003300
}

.dropdown-menu {
  background-color: #006B00
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-color: #002200
}

.navbar-inverse {
  background-image: none;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  background-image: none;
}

.navbar-inverse {
  border-color: #003300
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: #FFCC00
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a:focus {
  color: #FFCC00
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.open>a:focus {
  color: #FFCC00
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #FFCC00
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
  color: #FFFFFF
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #FFCC00
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-top-color: #FFFFFF
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>.dropdown>a:hover .caret {
  border-bottom-color: #FFFFFF
}
```

https://codepen.io/ericagulto/pen/KgdyqJ

Comment: I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8878033/how-to-make-twitter-bootstrap-menu-dropdown-on-hover-rather-than-click which seems to answer your question

Comment: I have added `.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}` and its working. Just to confirm ...This is only change i have added to my stylesheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your dropdown `<li>` to this

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropbtn">About <b class="caret"></b></a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Mission</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Careers</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
```

And add this to your CSS

```
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/Heliox/pen/ELBamB)